# In Python CSV module while reading and writing how to get rid of apostrophe

Tags: python, csv, apostrophe

[input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fibfo.jpg)   [Output file -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4KQW.jpg) In Python CSV module while reading and writing how to get rid of apostrophe my code is as following. original file dont have apostrophe but output have.

```
 import csv
 with open("test.csv",'r') as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f)
     for row in reader:
         writer=open('output.csv','a')
         writer.write(str(row))
         writer.write('\n')
         writer.close()
```

Comment: first correct your indent after with context

Comment: i corrected plz check

Comment: I didnt get it, the image you provided is from the input ou output?

Comment: that is out put

Comment: Scrip Price
AAPL 92.01
F 20.32
input

Comment: what about brackets?

Comment: no bracket in input

Comment: I believe you problem is that you are writing a list in the output
if you use print(type(row)) you will be able to see the var type
then you will know if it is a string or a list
is if is a list, you can try adding it without using str(), or creating another for to access each value of the list with row[index]

Comment: the bracket is an indicator of a list, lists are groups of data, in your case the list has two strings, thats why they have aposthophe (wich indicates string).
list values can be acessed using the index position like rows[0], rows[1]...

Comment: also, to help us provide better answers, always give information about input and expected output, so that people dont need to flood the comments. It is a good habit in stack to always provide plenty information about the problem while getting  straight to the point(wich you did) at the same time

Comment: row data type is list and without list can not be written with csv writer asking for string type

Comment: TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list

Comment: your list is a list of strings, you can use this normaly, you only need to pass them one at a time or join them isun python join() method. I believe it would be something like writer.write("".join(row)). This would turn the list into a string for the write method

Comment: Is the answer correct? is the problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

As write() asks for a string, you could write the elements one at a time. Try this:

```
writer=open('output.csv','a')
for row in reader:
    for element in row:
        #print(type(element))
        writer.write(element)
    writer.write('\n')
writer.close()
```

Also I believe the writer.close() whould be used only when the loop has already finished all the writing processes

Edit:In the print you can see that the type of the element var is a string, and not list

Comment: Thanks Breno its works element by element if there is no other way it is ok. But its is sample file actual data is big so it will take too much time because i have to manuplate data each second.

Comment: try this in the insertion
writer.write("".join(row))
also, if you are looking for performance opening and closing the file in each itteration should be slow.
when you keep the open and close outside of the loop you have to expend processing time only once, and not for each file row

Comment: you can also specify other separators such as (",".join(row)) ("/".join(row)) but I m sure that if you look into "python join String" you will find the better way for your data